# factor a joint likelihood of independent parameter

Tags: self-learning, bayesian, maximum-likelihood

I have a vector parameter $\vec{\theta} = [\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}, \theta_{3}]^{T}$, each of the component being independent random variable.

The data generating model is $p({\vec{h}} | \vec{\theta})$ with likelihood function $L(\vec{\theta} | \vec{h})$ and unninformative prior $\pi(\vec{\theta}) \propto \vec{1}$

Am I correct that the Bayesian posterior for the parameter vector, up to normalisation constant,
can be expressed as

$p(\vec{\theta} | \vec{h}) \propto L(\vec{\theta} | \vec{h}) = L(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}, \theta_{3} | \vec{h}) = L(\theta_{1} | \vec{h}).L(\theta_{2} | \vec{h}).L(\theta_{3} | \vec{h})$?

If not, where am I going wrong?